# Identification of a metal from group 2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, concentration, identification

> A chemist adds $\pu{0.115 g}$ of a group 2 element to water and the resulting solution is made up to $\pu{400 cm3}$ by adding distilled water. The equation for the reaction is shown below. $\ce{M}$ represents group 2 element.
>
> $$\ce{M + 2 H2O -> M(OH)2 + H2}$$
>
> The concentration of hydroxide ions $\ce{OH- (aq)}$ in the solution is $\pu{6.56e-3 mol dm-3}$. Determine the molar mass of $\ce{M}$ to one decimal place. Use your answer to identify $\ce{M}$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition molecular weight is mass $m$ divided by amount $n$, e.g. for the unknown metal $\ce{M}$:

$$M(\ce{M}) = \frac{m(\ce{M})}{n(\ce{M})} \tag{1} \label{eq:1}$$

From the chemical reaction of hydroxide formation one can deduce that $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{M}$ results in $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{M(OH)2}$. However, the amount of hydroxide-anions $\ce{OH-}$ in the solution (assuming complete dissociation) is twice as high as the amount of $\ce{M(OH)2}$. Hence

$$n(\ce{M}) = n(\ce{M(OH)2}) = \frac{n(\ce{OH-})}{2} = \frac{C(\ce{OH-}) \cdot V}{2} \tag{2} \label{eq:2}$$

where $C$ – concentration and $V$ – volume.

Plugging $n(\ce{M})$ from \eqref{eq:2} in \eqref{eq:1}, a final expression for the molecular weight can be established. Remember, before plugging in the numbers in make sure the units are unified.

> $$M(\ce{M}) = \frac{2 \cdot m(\ce{M})}{C(\ce{OH-}) \cdot V} = \frac{2 \cdot \pu{0.115 g}}{\pu{6.56e-3 mol dm-3} \cdot \pu{0.4 dm3}} = \pu{87.6 g mol-1} \tag{3} \label{eq:3}$$
>  The unknown metal appears to be strontium $\ce{Sr}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since as the molarity of the hydroxide is $\pu{6.56e-3 mol dm-3}$, by its stoichiometry the molarity of the metal must be half of that, i.e. $\pu{3.28e-3 mol dm-3}$.

We have $0.400\ \mathrm{dm^{-3}}$ of solution, so that contains $0.400\times \pu{3.28e-3 mol}$ of the element, which we also know weighs $0.115\ \mathrm{g}$ of that same element.

Dividing the mass of the element by the number of moles gives the molar mass to be: $87.6\ \mathrm{g/mol}$. That is strontium ($Sr$).